# How to read a folder name and output result to a string

Tags: python, string, os.walk

I have some code for reading directory names and file names

```
import os

#define the folder you want to use
myfolder = path/to/directory

#read directories
for dirs in os.walk(myfolder):        
    for dir in dirs:
        print("Directory name = %s" %dir
```

lets say inside -myfolder- I have a directory called -mysecondfolder-

is it possible to output the filename to a string

something like

```
for dirs in os.walk(myfolder):
    for dir in dirs:
        targetfolder="%dir"
```

Comment: Can you posting running code? Check out `os.walk()`... it emits `base, dirs, files` for each directory and they are all strings or lists of strings. Is it possible to output filename to a string? You bet.. its already a string.

Comment: The [os.walk documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk) includes an example of how to use it. Try adapting that then return here if you have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myfolder, topdown=False):
    targetfolder = dirs
```